# Replace Value with the number of times a group of numbers has appeared in the vector up to that point

Tags: r

I have a vector like this of 1s and 0s next to each other.

```
vec <- c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1)
```

I want to replace the 1s with the number the consecutive 1s showed up so the final vector would look like the one below.

```
vec1 <- c(1,1,1,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,3,3,3)
```

I am not sure how to even start with this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Similar to Ronak's answer: `tmp <- rle(vec); tmp$values <- cumsum(tmp$values) * tmp$values; inverse.rle(tmp)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using `rle` :

```
with(rle(vec), rep(values * cumsum(values), lengths))
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 2):

One `base R` option could be:

```
cumsum(vec & c(0, head(vec, -1)) == 0) * vec

[1] 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
vec[as.logical(vec)] <- as.integer(factor(rleid(vec)[as.logical(vec)]))
vec
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 3 3 3
```